# How to trigger click of an element (in the destination route component) after $state.go?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So im calling `$state.go` from a class after an element change event. I am able to change the state and go to the desired route. The component changes successfully as well.

The problem is: I need to click an element (programmatically) in the destination component but I'm unable to do so.

I tried using the `then`-function of state go. Referenced the element that I wanted to trigger. It just returns `ye.fn.init {}` whenever i try to log it. Maybe it just isn't loaded yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter in $state.go function like this:

```
$state.go('stateName', { param: "test" } );
```

Then in the component you can access that value and procceed with any action.
The way to get state params depends on the version of ui-router. (if you want specify the version)